# Fix error "There was a problem with reindexing process." or "Cannot initialize the indexer process."

Tags: reindex, indexer

I am having an issue reindexing my content in Magento. Both Product Flat Data and Product Category Data need to be re-indexed and it won't index for me.

I have tried deleting all content in /var/locks and /var/reports. I have also tried truncating/deleting the "mg_catalog_product_flat_1" table to no avail. When I check the logs it looks like the table still exists. In phpMyAdmin, the table is listed in the left hand structure but when I click it I see the below error:
[image]

In the admin panel I've received both "There was a problem with reindexing process."  and "Cannot initialize the indexer process.". I've also tried to reindex manually via SSH and I get the same errors. Under SSH, all of the other indexes succeed except the Product Flat Data and Product Category.

Since the table doesn't exist I'm not sure why my exception.log shows the following (Note: hashtags/pound symbol beforeline numbers has been omitted and extra line spaces have been added for clarity):

> 2014-08-04T19:23:39+00:00 DEBUG (7): Exception message: SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'mg_catalog_product_flat_1' already exists
>
> Trace: 0 /home/waterwal/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
>
> 1 /home/waterwal/public_html/app/code/core/Zend/Db/Statement.php(291): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
>
> 2 /home/waterwal/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(480): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
>
> 3 /home/waterwal/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('CREATE TABLE `m...', Array)
>
> 4 /home/waterwal/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(428): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('CREATE TABLE `m...', Array)
>
> 5 /home/waterwal/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(2117): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('CREATE TABLE `m...')
>
> 6 /home/waterwal/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Product/Flat/Indexer.php(701): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->createTable(Object(Varien_Db_Ddl_Table))
>
> 7 /home/waterwal/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Product/Flat/Indexer.php(1389): Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Flat_Indexer->prepareFlatTable(1)
>
> 8 /home/waterwal/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Flat/Indexer.php(296): Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Flat_Indexer->reindexAll()
>
> 9 /home/waterwal/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Indexer/Flat.php(350): Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Flat_Indexer->reindexAll()
>
> 10 /home/waterwal/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Process.php(210): Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Indexer_Flat->reindexAll()
>
> 11 /home/waterwal/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Process.php(258): Mage_Index_Model_Process->reindexAll()
>
> 12 /home/waterwal/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Index/controllers/Adminhtml/ProcessController.php(182): Mage_Index_Model_Process->reindexEverything()
>
> 13 /home/waterwal/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Index_Adminhtml_ProcessController->massReindexAction()
>
> 14 /home/waterwal/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('massReindex')
>
> 15 /home/waterwal/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
>
> 16 /home/waterwal/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
>
> 17 /home/waterwal/public_html/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
>
> 18 /home/waterwal/public_html/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
>
> 19 {main}

If anyone has any suggestions I will definitely try them, I really need to get this fixed! Thanks!

Comment: If you have any custom extension, then disable it.
Then re-index again
The problem probably is with the customization done in the catalog related extension.